# Get Target Item in Language not working on custom pipeline processor

Tags: publishing-service

I am working on a custom pipeline processor on Publish where I am trying to use code

```
context.PublishHelper.GetTargetItemInLanguage(item.ID,Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("es"));
```

But this is returning NULL always.

Comment: what version of Sitecore? Could you check the logs if item.ID has value and that context object is not null

Comment: Sitecore 9.2.0 & both ID and Context object has value @SumitUpadhyay

Comment: You run that code on CM server? I'm not sure if CM server has access to target item if publishing is executed by PublishingService. You may try to ask Sitecore Support for some help